# Online RTE (Rich Text Editor) javascript library with data uri capability

Tags: javascript, rich-text-editor, data-uri

I'm looking for a RTE javascript library (e.g. tinyMce) to allow user to create rich web content. I'm very keen to find one that is:

- lightweight (not a must)
- allow image upload that can transform binary data into "data uri", i'd like to embed uploaded images into the page that the user is editing. If this feature is not provided with any RTEs, please recommend one that may extend this function easily.
- multiple languages support including asian languages.
- preferrably work as a jQuery plug-in.

Please share your experience if you have done this before.

Comment: Seem it is difficult one with your request. The most advanced RTE i discovered are the the google doc or the MS Office Live. And YUI RTE also good to use.

Comment: Sorry, i just re-edited the title and content to clarify it. I'm actually after a javascript library for RTE which can be used for a website i'm developing. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: I try tinymce, but seem it is not very handy when acts as a rich text editor. Most advanced online text editor is from google doc,  but i don't think it can plug in to other website. you can take a look here for different RTE http://www.webdesignerdepot.com/2008/12/20-excellent-free-rich-text-editors/